# MVC Core with Angular2: MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After adding the following "Angular 2" dependencies to MVC wwwroot folder 
(Copying from "node_modules" to "wwwroot/lib/ng2")

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "0.5.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.17",
```

I got the following error when trying to rebuild the project

Error   MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.   Project.Name    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"   214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project compiles successfully when I deleted the folder "wwwroot/lib/ng2/@angular/compiler-cli". but I don't know yet if this will affect angular2 development or not?